# .bat file not executing in jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, testng

i have made a main() class,which is calling testng.xml.In the testNG.xml,i have coded for all the testNG classes(test cases ,done by selenium).Now I have created a JAR of the main() class.Then I have created a .bat file to execute the JAR.

**Problem:**
I am trying to integrate my code with JENKINS,but each build is getting failed due to org.testng.TestNG Exception and NoclassFoundException

But whenever I am executing the JAR through .bat file(not in JENKINS) created.Its executing fine.

Comment: post a copy of your code, it will help us help you

Comment: Change your .bat file to add the line `set` all by itself at the top.  This will print out all your environment variables.  Now run the script in the situation where it works, and then run it in Jenkins.  The output in each case will show all your environment variables.  Compare the output of both cases to find out which environment variables are missing when Jenkins runs it.

Comment: how your trying to build your java code in Jenkins , and how your calling bat file

Answer (score 0):

**Step1**
Add "Execute Windows batch command" from the job config.
[image]

**Step2**

```
 cd your_bat_script_directory
 foo.bat
```